# How to delete and add specific columns in multiple excel files

Tags: excel, edit

I have a file with 5 columns :

A || B || C || D || E

and I want to delete the E column and add 2 new ones with the same content in the cells. I tried to find a way in excel but it is impossible.

I used MACROS record in excel as people have suggested me to use the MACROS in my original query. But the problem is that the excel files I have, have different row numbers. So, in file one I need to add a new column with 10 rows (same text inside) and in another I need to add 2 rows.

How can I program that in the MACROS? More specifically, I want to convert this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

I only need the columns shown in picture 2. I no longer need to delete the rest. I use the files to import them on openCRM.

Comment: which are the criteria to kno where and how much colum to add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a excel macro

```
sub ColReplaceInCurrentSheet ()
dim LastCellRow as integer

'uncomment for removing warning message
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("E:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

' Define last row of data
Range("A65534").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
LastCellRow = Selection.Row

for each ThisCell in Range ( "E1:F" & LastCellRow)
   ThisCell.value='The Value I want here'
 next

end sub
```

- Assuming number of row is equal to the last (lower) filled cell in column A (arbitrary limited at 65534 here)
- You could put any value that you want in the cell, i set it to an abritrary string here
- macro is to put in a extra excel file so you can call it (file need to be open in excel) from any other excel
- macro work on current active sheet.

Comment: I tried the MACROS record. It did work for some files. But the problem is that some files have more rows. So it doesn't delete them effectively.

Comment: I actually need to add some columns that are going to have exactly the same content each. But the number of the rows is not stable in the files. In some I have 5 rows, in some others I have 10. 

At the end of the page I have 3 columns that need to be deleted. But their position is varying depending on the row numbers of the previous content.